# How do I update a Cloudfront URL redirect using S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have created a redirect from url get.blahblah.com to point to a beta version of our app.  I created an S3 bucket, then created a Cloudfront distribution using it, and then added an A entry in Route 53 and everything is working.

Now I wanted to test out updating the URL in S3 so that once we update our final app we can update the URL.  I changed the S3 bucket redirect to google.com.  When I click on the link in the S3 bucket it correctly redirects to google.com.

But when I go to my get.blahblah.com website, it's still pointing to our beta app and not google.com.

Is there something I have to do in order to make the redirect url "update" in all of this?  I'm an AWS noob and getting here took me some time because it's not too straight forward in the guides.

EDIT:

Here is the cache TTL I am talking about that I modified:

[image]

Comment: Did you invalidate the cache in CloudFront?

Comment: It sounds like you need to adjust the caching TTL

Comment: I adjusted the default and maimum TTL in Cloudfront to 10 minutes (600s) and the minimum is still 0, and redeployed and it's still not going to the new one.  And that was like an hour ago.  Is there a way to specifically invalidate the cache in Cloudfront?  I haven't seen that option.

Comment: Okay so I googled and added an Invalidation rule of * and after that was done, it appears to work in my browser if I clear cache.  However if I don't clear cache it doesn't do that.  I tested this out in Chrome and Firefox.  Is there a way to make it so that isn't necessary?